# How do I force Windows 7 to double click control panel icons?

Tags: windows-7, icons, control-panel

For everything else, icon-wise, I can double click.  But using the classic control panel in Windows 7, they appear to still be links, so when just single clicking it, will launch the applet, which is not behaviour I want.  If this can be done via group policy, that'll be doubly awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this behaviour can be modified, and frankly am not sure why it's such an issue. I too prefer double-click-to-launch everywhere, but hardly even use the Control Panel directly to be bothered by this. I find it *far* simpler to type a few words in the Start Menu and launch the chosen applet directly.

Anyway, one possible workaround could be to use an [**All Tasks** folder shortcut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Master_Control_Panel_shortcut), which will allow you to double-click to launch applets, just as you prefer.

[image: 1]

Comment: I will use this as a workaround for myself.  For my users I guess it won't be an issue.  I just find it difficult to explain to people certain things are single clicked, some things are double clicked.  They are used to double clicking icons, but with hyperlinks, they see it as an icon they double click that as well, including hyperlinks on the web!

Comment: I know just what you're referring to, so on their systems why don't you set *everything* to be single-clicked, to reduce confusion? I too found it really difficult to teach my (older) relatives and actually realised how some things we take for granted and never even give a second thought to can seem so inconsistent/confusing to absolute newbies. Forget *where* to single and double-click, even teaching them *how* to double-click properly was a real challenge, even after increasing the delay.